# How to create this query in Parse cloud Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I need to create / execute following SQL query in Parse Javascript SDK.

```
Select * form xyz table where xyz.username in [select username from users where gender = "male"];
```

Not able to figure out how to do this using Parse SDK , please help.

added code :

```
var gender = request.params.gender;
var users = [];
console.log(gender);
if(strcmp1(gender , "All") != 0)
{
    var genderQuery = new Parse.Query("User");
    genderQuery.equalTo("gender",gender);
    var scoreQuery = new Parse.Query("JournalEntry");

    scoreQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("userName", "username", genderQuery);
    scoreQuery.find({ 
        success: function(results) {
            for(j = 0; j < results.length ; j++)
            {
                var entry = results[j];
                users.push(entry.get("username"));
            }
            response.success(users);    
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [matchesKeyInQuery](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matchesKeyInQuery)

```
var maleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
maleQuery.equalTo("gender", "male");

var xyzQuery = new Parse.Query("xyz");
xyzQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("username", "username", maleQuery);
xyzQuery.find({ 
  success: function(results) {

  }
});
```

Comment: can you check the code i added ? it returns empty array even when there is reasonable data available in both tables

Comment: First try the genderQuery by itself and check if it returns any users. Then, try your scoreQuery with only `find()` to check if it returns any JournalEntry. Is it `userName` or `username`? Is it `"User"` or `Parse.User`?